# Array display's value twice in table

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code:

```
$field = 0;
echo "<table border='1'>";    

$inlcude_copy = $inlcude;

echo "<tr>";
foreach ($ad as $post)
{
    if ($field < 3)
    {
        echo "<td>$post</td>"; //first three values are displayed in the 
        $field++;              // first row
    }
    if($field == 3) //closes first row
    {
        echo "</tr>";
        $field++; 
        //array_splice($post, 2);
    }
    if ($field > 3) //rest of $post values get added in a single column
    {         
        $in = array_shift($inlcude_copy); //acts as another foreach loop to display 
                                          //second array in seperate column
        echo "<tr><td>$post</td><td>$in</td></tr>";   
    }

}
echo '</table>';
```

Here the problem: The third element in the $ad array gets displayed in the third column of the first row and in the first column of the second row. However, when checking the elements in the array, this is what I get:

```
Array(
    [0]=> Chem
    [1]=> apple
    [2]=> fixed
    [3]=> orange
    [4]=> fish )
```

As you can see, the third element (fixed) is only in one location in the array buy gets displayed twice in my table. I've tried using array_splice($post, 2) but that did not work. I am absolutely stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When `$field` is `2`, it matches the condition in the first `if`, you increment it.  It then matches the condition in the second `if`; you increment it.  It then matches the condition in the third `if` - ***all in the same iteration*** of `$ad` where `$post=='fixed'`.  ***See:*** [`else if` control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increment your `$field` value with IF stament. This leads to a scenario where multiple IFs are validated as true ($field=2 AND $field=3`)
You can modify your code so as to increment $field only once and use IF..ELSE statements.

```
foreach ($ad as $post)
{
    if ($field < 3)
    {
        echo "<td>$post</td>"; //first three values are displayed in the 
    }
    elseif($field == 3) //closes first row
    {
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    else // if ($field > 3) rest of $post values get added in a single column
    {         
        $in = array_shift($inlcude_copy); //acts as another foreach loop to display 
                                          //second array in seperate column
        echo "<tr><td>$post</td><td>$in</td></tr>";   
    }
$field++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Carefully trace your code. After executing the first if-statement. What is the value stored in `$field`? Hint: After the first time executing it, `$field` equals 1. What is it equal to on the *third* iteration? 3. What is the result of the boolean expression in the *second* if-statement after the execution of the first if-statment? Hint: `$field == 3` is the same as `3 == 3`, which is true. So that if-statement is ALSO executed on the third iteration of the `foreach` loop.